# First field missing from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The first field "Cliche" is refusing to be displayed, the "description" field is displaying correctly. Not sure what I am doing wrong. [image]

**common_linkers/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Cliche:</strong></td>
        <td <%= @common_linker.cliche %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Description:</strong></td>
        <td> <%= @common_linker.description %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Created by:</strong></td>
         <td><%= @common_linker.user.email %></td> 
      </tr>
```

**common_linkers_controller.rb**

```
class CommonLinkersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_common_linker, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :votes]
  before_action :set_movie
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @common_linkers = CommonLinker.all
    respond_with(@common_linkers)
  end

  def show
    @common_linker = CommonLinker.find(params[:id])
  end

   def vote
      value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
     @common_linker = CommonLinker.find(params[:id])
     @common_linker.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "thanks for the vote"
   end


  def new
    @common_linker = CommonLinker.new
    respond_with(@common_linker)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @common_linker = CommonLinker.new(common_linker_params)
    @common_linker.user_id = current_user.id
    @common_linker.movie_id = @movie.id

    if @common_linker.save
        redirect_to @movie
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @common_linker.update(common_linker_params)
    respond_with(@common_linker)
  end

  def destroy
    @common_linker.destroy
    respond_with(@common_linker)
  end

  private
  def set_common_linker
    @common_linker = CommonLinker.find(params[:id])
    end

   def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
   end

  def common_linker_params
    params.require(:common_linker).permit(:cliche, :description)
    end
end
```

**common_linker.rb**

```
class CommonLinker < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :movie

   has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :movies do 
   resources :common_linkers do
      member { post :vote }

     end
  end
   root 'movies#index'


end
```

I am still learning, but I feel like I am missing something big here. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo:

```
<td <%= @common_linker.cliche %></td>
```

Should be:

```
<td> <%= @common_linker.cliche %></td>
```